# Не появляется кнопка закрвающая окно

Tags: html, css

Привет всем! Учу CSS и не получается сделать появление закрывающей кнопки (.close) при открытии модального окна... Почему-то не срабатывает display:block при фокусе, хотя вроде бы все просто и должно без проблем работать...

```css
.galery_img_pushkin{
    float:left; margin:100px 0 0 230px;  
}
    .galery_img_pushkin a{
         display:block; cursor:zoom-in;  
    }
        .galery_img_pushkin a:focus{
             position:fixed; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; height:170px; width:300px;margin:auto; border: 12px solid rgba(255,255,255,1.0); border-radius:10px; cursor:default; box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(30,30,30, 1.0), 0 0 0 1000px rgba(130,130,130,.5); z-index:2;
        }
            .close{
                display:none; background:rgba(172,205,0,1.00); height:55px; width:55px; position:absolute; top:70px; left:560px; z-index:3; text-align:center; font-size:40px; color:#fff;
            }
.galery_img_pushkin a:focus .close{
    display:block; 
}
.close:hover{
    background:rgba(245,140,0,1.00); cursor:pointer;
}
                .pushkin_01{
                    background:rgba(100,130,130,.5); height:100px; width:200px
                }
```

```html
<div class="galery_img_pushkin">
  <div class="close">x</div>
  <a href="#" class="pushkin_01"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: нельзя обращаться от потомков к родителю. нельзя

Comment: Понятно, значит так не работает... а как эта тема называется можете сказать? а-то где учу, читаю про это ничего не говорится(...

Comment: не знаю как тема называется.... смысл в том, что обращаться можно только вглубь `родитель > потомок > потомок > потомок`, а не наоборот. то есть `потомок > родитель > родитель` через CSS нельзя. Поэтому какая-нибудь конструкция вида `.galery_img_pushkin a.pushkin_01:hover .close` - ничего не даст и бесполезна..... Если нужно поменять состояние родителя в зависимости от состояния ребенка, то скорее всего нужен js....... в вашем случае если нужна именно зависимость от фокуса над `a` - то на css нельзя так... если брать как зависимость от `.galery_img_pushkin:hover` - тогда можно

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.galery_img_pushkin a:focus .close замените на .galery_img_pushkin:hover .close

Comment: Немного не тот эфект я думал получить, но спасибо, теперь хоть понятнее почему не сработало...